# What other languages that let you save and restore application state to disk, like sbcl, and factor?

Tags: persistence

Two that I know of are:

- [sbcl](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/Saving-a-Core-Image.html): sb-ext:save-lisp-and-die
- [factor](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/article-images.html): save-image-and-exit

any others? 
I am not interested in saving state outside of the application (handles to external resources, file objects etc...), just data and functions.

Comment: SWI-Prolog has qsave_program: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=qsave_program/2

Answer (score 0):

Squeak(Smalltalk): SmalltalkImage current snapshot: true andQuit: false.

Like above cases, Squeak Smalltalk let developers/users save/restore the application state to disk using image file like sbcl(or other lisp system).

Comment: I don't understand the answer. Could you please expand?

Comment: Ah, I have tried to make as same style as possible with original question. (But it seems that I failed).